# cant iterate through members of a server discord API

Tags: api, loops, discord.py

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=':')
token = ''

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('BOT ONLINE')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.channel
    if message.content.startswith('/'):
        if message.content.startswith("/users"):
            # FOR LOOP IN QUESTION ---------------
            for guild in client.guilds:
                for member in guild.members:
                    print(member)  # or do whatever you wish with the member detail

client.run(token)


print("Bot Finished")
```

When I run this code all it returns is the bot name twice. The server has two members, myself and the bot. I need to iterate through every member of the server. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply didn't enable `intents.members`

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=":", intents=intents)
```

Also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

Reference:

- [`intents.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents%20members#discord.Intents.members)
- [How to enable privileged intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents%20members#privileged-intents)

Comment: Whoopsies, i'm dumb. Thank you so much for your answer!!! its working now